# PHP - reading date from json and modifying as date not string

Tags: php, date, type-conversion

I have a json file that is just a date - current_date.json:

```
["2022-01-28"]
```

I then try to read this date with PHP like so:

```
$string = file_get_contents("current_date.json");
$json = json_decode($string,true);

$end = date($json[0]);
$begin = date($end, strtotime("-1 days"));
```

This gives my $end variable as a string not a date and the $begin variable is not modified it is just the same string.

What is the best way to get these variables as dates?

The reason I am doing it like this is I want to work backwards one day at a time at which point I will overwrite the date in the json file so the next time this file runs it will get the previous day.

Comment: Why are you passing `2022-01-28` as first parameter to `date`? That function wants a date _format_ as first parameter.

Comment: [Read the Manual - `date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) SO is not a replacement for the manual. The manual should be your first port of call and not SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let `$begin` value like this

```
$begin = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($end."-1 days")); // 2022-01-27
```